# Scala Parsing Combinators syntax error with ~ function

Tags: scala, parsing, scala-3

I'm making a free time project with scala parsing combinators, following [this guide](https://enear.github.io/2016/03/31/parser-combinators/), added to project with sbt with:

```scala
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "2.0.0"
```

I have a Lexer that compile, but the parser give me this error: `method ~ in class Parser has changed semantics in version SpecificScalaVersion(2,9,0,Final): The call-by-name argument is evaluated at most once per constructed Parser object, instead of on every need that arises during parsing.` on this line of code:

```scala
import scala.util.parsing.input.Positional

sealed trait AbstractSyntaxTree extends Positional

sealed trait Instruction extends AbstractSyntaxTree

final case class Label(text: String) extends Instruction

package svm.parser

import scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers
import scala.util.parsing.input.{NoPosition, Position, Reader}
import svm.{ParserError, Location}
import svm.lexer._

object SVMParser extends Parsers {

  def label: Parser[Label] = positioned {
    identifier ~ COL() ^^ { case IDENTIFIER(s) ~ _ => Label(s) }
  }
}
```

This is the output of `sbt compile`:

```scala
[error] -- [E114] Syntax Error: /home/ap/Documents/scala/simple-stack-virtual-machine/src/main/scala/svm/parser/SVMParser.scala:59:15 
[error] 59 |    identifier ~ COL() ^^ { case IDENTIFIER(s) ~ _ => Label(s) }
[error]    |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
[error]    |     |method ~ in class Parser has changed semantics in version SpecificScalaVersion(2,9,0,Final): The call-by-name argument is evaluated at most once per constructed Parser object, instead of on every need that arises during parsing.
[error] Explanation
[error] ===========
[error] The      |method ~ in class Parser is marked with @migration indicating it has changed semantics
[error] between versions and the -Xmigration settings is used to warn about constructs
[error] whose behavior may have changed since version change.
```

I'm using wrong the `~` operator?

Comment: also asked at https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/o32i2u/scala_parsing_combinators_problem/

Comment: offhand, it looks to me like like a combination of 2 things: the scala-parser-combinators library contains antiquated `@migration` annotations, and then for some reason (that I don't understand and haven't attempted to understand, since I mainly work in Scala 2) the Scala 3 compiler is treating them as errors rather than merely as advisory. I have submitted https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators/pull/405 to remove the annotations

Comment: So I don't have to be warned about that? I've to check my scalacOptions @SethTisue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about how Scala 3 interprets `@migration`